# How can I .htaccess redirect multiple domains with and without www

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to make multiple domain names show the same page, however one specific domain name NEEDS www. in front of the domain name, and I don't want the other domain names to require www.  If I remove the OR the first rule works great, but the second rule should force domain and domain4 to use www. no matter what.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?(domain2|domain3)\.(com|info)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)(domain|domain4)\.(com|info)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://%1%2.%3/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What URL is this rule redirecting to?

Comment: domain.info = www.thesmartass.info (the domain that NEEDS www.) domain2.info = www.thesmartass2.info (a domain that only loads on my own computer for testing) domain3=absinthemynd.com an alias domain, that one needs to be able to loads without typing www